# How can I plot multiple sequence alignment in R as a boxplot and scatterplot:

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

- I've fasta file contains 16 protein and I aligned them with package ("msa").
  now I need to Visualize my results of similar sequences using boxplots and scatterplot
- I read about "ggmsa" but it's not working on my R version, and I tried many other version but it's still not working.
- my code:

```
#if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  #install.packages("BiocManager")

#BiocManager::install("msa")
library("msa")

mySequenceFile <-file.choose(file.choose())
mySequences <- readAAStringSet(mySequenceFile)

## ----doAlignment-----------------------------------------------
Multiple_Alignment <- msa(mySequences)


## ----showWholeWidth--------------------------------------------
sink("align.txt") #Send R Output to a File
print(Multiple_Alignment, show="complete")
sink()
```

Comment: Not reproducible as no data examples. `dput()` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The Bioconductor package `DECIPHER` have a very good tool for visualizing sequences in your browser.

It doesn't work with `msa`'s object type but works with regular `Biostrings` stringsets.

```
# load in your library
library(DECIPHER)

# load the example DNA sequences
db <- system.file("extdata", "Bacteria_175seqs.sqlite", package="DECIPHER")
dna <- SearchDB(db) # non-coding ribosomal RNA gene sequences

# example of using the defaults with DNA sequences
BrowseSeqs(dna) # view the XStringSet in your default browser window
```

These example sequences are pre-aligned, but anything you can align and convert to an `XStringSet` can be visualized with `BrowseSeqs()`.